# remember state after external link redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having trouble trying to get the page to set a few localStorage variables; the problem is when I click on an internal link (like '/about') then the localStorage variables are set and the map retains the zoom and center positions but when I click on an external link (like google.com) on the website it does not update to the new position and zoom on the map when going back.

```
if(localStorage.lat) {
   map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(localStorage.lat, localStorage.lng));
   map.setZoom(parseInt(localStorage.zoom)); 
}


$('a').on('click', function() { 
   localStorage.lat = map.getCenter().lat();
   localStorage.lng = map.getCenter().lng();
   localStorage.zoom = map.getZoom();
});
```

The external link is basically within an infoWindow which is open upon clicking the marker on google maps api v3.

```
var contentString = '<div class="infowindowcontent bk">'
contentString += '<p class="viewLink"><a href="external link"</a></p>' 
contentString += '</div>';
```

I am using infoWindow like this:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip Is that good enough; I mean i'm not to sure what else I can give you?

Comment: A [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) that demonstrates the issue (in the question itself) is what I am looking for (not lots of disconnected pieces of code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have decided to use [Google Maps Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) in order to solve the issue instead of doing it based on click of a tag as it wasn't picking up links within the infoWindow (Google Map API function):

```
map.addListener('zoom_changed', function(){
  localStorage.zoom = map.getZoom();
});

map.addListener('center_changed', function(){
  localStorage.lat = map.getCenter().lat();
  localStorage.lng = map.getCenter().lng();
});
```